# UI Issues between 3.5" and 4" iPhone screens

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I am having an issue going between an iPhone 4 and 5 screen with my UI - it's best shown with these shots

[image: Oversized top]

[image: Normal sized top]

[image: Normal sized bottom]

[image: Oversized bottom]

Each of these shots have the automatic constraints added with a UIScrollView between each top and bottom. The top bar is a fixed size of 320 x 56 with the xib designer set to be the same on both.

On the 4/4S, the UI works perfectly. On the 5/5C/5S, the UI shows these problems in random areas.

Is there a way to avoid this issue for future reference and to correct this in my current app?

Comment: It is possible you're having a problem with automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets .. maybe read up on that as a starter?? Hope it helps

Comment: what do you mean the "top bar" is a fixed size?  your top bar, or the statusBar ?

Comment: the top bar (green one) is a fixed size image - 320x50 and is placed on the UI in the xib and looks fine in there

Comment: @JoeBlow - thanks for that, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue

Comment: OK, you've definitely just got some problem in the storyboard.  Your "simulated metric - size" should be "none".  You'd have to post some screen shots of your XIB setup showing the values etc. you've chosen, and I'm sure someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add delta in your code or in IB if screen height (self.view.frame.size.height) more than 480.

Comment: According to the docs though, if I'm using auto layout that shouldn't be needed